# Purpose of `return`

Tags: java, return, binary-search-tree

folks, what is the purpose of the single `return` statement inside a method. Does it stop the loop? If not, what exactly does it do? Consider the following example:

```
class BinaryTree{

    Node root;

    public void addNode(int key, String name){
        Node newNode = new Node(key, name); 
        if(root == null){
            root = newNode;
        }
        else{
            Node current = root; 
            Node parent = root;
            while(current.key != key){
                parent = current;
                if(key > current.key){
                    current = current.rightChild;
                    if(current == null){
                        parent.rightChild = newNode;
                        return;
                    }
                }
                else{
                    current = current.leftChild;
                    if(current == null){
                        parent.leftChild = newNode;
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Alnitak, I would really appreciate if you could give me the link for that

Comment: `return;` returns from the method. It exits the loop like you said. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.17

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `return` statement terminates the function. It's useful to stop the execution of a `void` function that does not actually return any value. In this case, once you've found the right place for the new node and added it, there's no point to continue executing the function, so `return` is used.

Comment: But why not `break` instead of `return` ? @Mureinik

Comment: @John `break` would terminate the loop, and then go on to execute the rest of the function - only there's nothing more to execute, so in this case they would have the same effect. `return`, however, carries the meaning of "I'm done with the function it it should be terminated", which is more appropriate here, IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't only stop the loop, it returns void (nothing) from the function. So basically it stops the function.

Answer (score 1):

Because the function returns void. The return just ends the function and returns void.

Answer (score 0):

To speak formally, a `return` with no expression will complete the execution abruptly (per [JLS 14.17](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.17)).  `return` will also return control back to its caller.

It's possible and permissible to have a method that returns `void` with an empty `return` block. The intent here is to cease operations in the method if a certain condition is met.

This would be no different than if you had written `break` in the loop in place of `return`, since in this context, they accomplish the same thing: they would both terminate the loop and exit the method (by consequence of there being no more lines to execute).

In a scenario like this, the intent would be clearer if `break` were used, since `return` can confuse student or junior developers.  Just note that, unlike `break`, which *would* allow you to run code after the loop, `return` wouldn't.